# How to change values within a Pandas df using values in a different Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a main data frame that has price information on various items. Many of these prices are missing, and thus have NaN values.

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id' : [1,2,3,4], 'item_price' : [2.3,NaN, 3.3, NaN]})
main_df
```

I would like to solve this issue by using another data frame that I have, which has the average price for every item (no NaN values)

```
ref_df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id' : [1,2,3,4], 'item_avg_price' : [2.3,3.5, 3.3, 4.3]})
ref_df
```

I would like to replace the NaN values in item_price in the main data frame with the avg. price of that item, which is stored in the reference df, as such

```
goal = pd.DataFrame({'item_id' : [1,2,3,4], 'item_price' : [2.3,3.5, 3.3, 4.3]})
goal
```

I've been trying to do this by using a for loop which goes through every row in the main data frame, checks if its price is missing, and if so replaces it with the average price of that item. Not only have I not been able to get this to work, but I think there is probably a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Try pandas `fillna`

Comment: That helps, thank you!